# What package is a tool to check hard drive health

Tags: hard-drive

I have seen it before... some kind of system information tool which among other things was giving out some diagnostic info about my hard drives... like number off r/w errors,  bad sectors etc. Im on Bodhi linux now which is ubuntu based and doesnt have anything like this installed.  Please help me to locate which package I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package is called `gnome-disks` or `gnome-disk-utility`.

Comment: @Evzin How to use them at practise?

Answer (score 0):

SMART is a usefull utilty (Self Monitoring Analysis and Reporting Technology)

smartctl --smart=on --offlineauto=on --saveauto=on /dev/hda
                                              (Enables SMART on first disk)

smartctl --test=long /dev/hda          (Executes extended disk self-test)

smartctl --attributes --log=selftest --quietmode=errorsonly /dev/hda
                                      (Prints Self-Test & Attribute errors)